# coda slider go direct to specific slide by id

Tags: javascript, slider, coda

I just edited slider of content using [coda slider](http://kevinbatdorf.github.com/codaslider/).

So I have a photo gallery and when I click on any photo it open a page with coda slider. Which image is clicked, that image is the first slider. Clicking on the next, the slider switch to the next photo, but clicking on the previous photo, the slider go back to the beginning and not to the previous photo.

In the gallery, it looks like this:

```
<div class="one_fourth">                        
     <div class="imgNikon">
            <a href="../photos/bw_slider.html#2"><img src="../photos/2.jpg" width="150" height="100" />
            <span class="imgFrameNikon"></span></a>
   </div>
   <a href="../photos/bw_slider.html#2"><h6 style="margin-bottom:20px;"align="center">2<br /><br /></h6></a>
</div>  


<div class="one_fourth">                        
        <div class="imgNikon">
            <a href="../photos/bw_slider.html#1"><img src="../photos/1.jpg" width="150" height="100"/>
            <span class="imgFrameNikon"></span></a>
    </div>
    <a href="../photos/bw_slider.html#1"><h6 style="margin-bottom:20px;"align="center">1<br /><br /></h6></a>
</div>
```

So, bw_slider.html is the page that contain the coda slider.
Continuation of the link #1 and in the other case #2 is a direct link to specific slide that contain that id.

In the coda slider it look like this with much more slides:

```
<div id="1">
<h2>1</h2>
  <img src="1.jpg"  width="600" height="400" />
    <div class="photo_gallery"> 
              <p >Some text...</p>
    </div>
</div>
<div id="2">
<h2>2</h2>
  <img src="2.jpg"  width="600" height="400" />
    <div class="photo_gallery"> 
              <p >Some text...</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

The js of coda slider is on the link above.

Does anyone have any idea how to avoid a return to the beginning when starting slider from the middle of the slider content.

Comment: Where have you defined the id's `1` and `2`?

Comment: Hi, I defined id's 1 and 2 in the gallery: <a href="../photos/bw_slider.html#2". So when you click at the image it opens a new page with contain coda slider.